# php array compare function from JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I need a little bit of help with this situation.

Within our company we use a clocktool to check in and out employees. In our mainhall we have a big screen with some slides with company related information. One slide contains a page that shows the checked-in employees. This page checks refreshes automaticly every 5 minutes.

I made the script in PHP. It reads a JSON file from an endpoint which is provided by the clocktool. This JSON file contains a list of all the employees who are at the office.

The exentension I try to add to this script is the following:

`<?php
$checkedinPREV = array("John", "Mike", "Elisa", "PersonX", "PersonY"); //contains array of employees from previous check
$checkedinNOW = array("John", "Mike", "Elisa", "MisterS", "Rico"); //contains array of employees from current check`

`$checked = in;
$checkedin = CompareArray($checked, $checkedinPREV, $checkedinNOW);
foreach ($checkedin as $value) {
    echo "$value checked in<br>"; //output should be: Misters checked in<br>Rico checked in<br>
}`

`$checked = out;
$checkedout = CompareArray($checked, $checkedinPREV, $checkedinNOW);
foreach ($checkedout as $value) {
    echo "$value checked out<br>"; //output should be: PersonX checked out<br>PersonY checked out<br>
}`

So the "CompareArray()" function I need to build, does a compare on the two arrays... 
- if the $checked variable is "in", then in outputs an array with the newly added names comparing $checkedinPREV, $checkedinNOW...
- if the $checked variable is "out", then in outputs an array with the removed names comparing $checkedinPREV, $checkedinNOW...

I think is should use something like this in my function:

```
if $checked == out // shorted out
```

`$result = array_diff($checkedinPREV, $checkedinNOW);`

```
if $checked == in // shorted out
```

`$result = array_diff($checkedinNOW, $checkedinPREV);`

Am I on the right way? Or is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `array_diff()`

```
function CompareArray ($checked , $array1 , $array2){
  if($checked == "in"){
   return array_diff($array2,$array1);
  }
  else if($checked == "out"){
   return array_diff($array1,$array2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
//in before
$inPrev = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
//in now
$inNow = [1, 2, 4, 6];

//people that left
$peopleOut = array_diff($inPrev, $inNow);
//people that came
$newIn = array_diff($inNow, $inPrev);
```